# Is there a way to define an alias for a hardware Serial

Tags: serial, softwareserial

I'm porting some code from Arduino Uno over to a Mega and I want to replace a SoftwareSerial defined in the previous code with one of the built-in UARTs.

Rather than go through and replace all references to the serial port, I'd prefer to create an alias for Serial1. The alias can be a constant.

In my old code, I setup the Software Serial as follows:

```
//SoftwareSerial HMI(HMIRX, HMITX); // Define software serial for the HMI adapter (RX, TX)
```

I"m not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is simple
`#define HMI Serial1`

Comment: Alternatively: `HardwareSerial &HMI = Serial1;`